# sendSignedTransaction vs sendRawTransaction

Tags: web3js, signature, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction, sendsignedtransaction

`sendSignedTransaction` vs `sendRawTransaction`: What's the difference?

They both require the transaction to be already signed (and therefore hashed). Both work with local keys and not hosted keys. Both take the hex string format of the signed transaction as input.

Are these two the same function with different names?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `sendSignedTransaction` exists from web3.js v1.x. It was previosuly named `sendRawTransaction` in v0.20.x.

The implementation detail changed v1 uses promises as is fully async. On the other hand v0.20 uses callbacks but it as a synchronous version.